# jQuery infinite loop

Tags: jquery

I want to have a function executed once on mouseenter then on mouseleave I would like to have the element to go back to its state.

My code produces an infinite loop. The mouse enters and the element flips infinitely until my mouse leaves.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var flipfunc = function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        if (!elem.data('flipped')) {
            elem.flip({
                direction: 'lr',
                speed: 250,
                onBefore: function() {
                    elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
                }
            });
            elem.data('flipped', true);
            elem.addClass('sponsorFlipped');
            //elem.unbind('mouseenter', flipfunc);
        }
        else {
            elem.revertFlip();
            // Unsetting the flag:
            elem.data('flipped', false)
            //elem.unbind('mouseleave', rflipfunc);
        }

    }

    $('.sponsorFlip').bind('mouseenter', flipfunc);

    //$('.sponsorFlipped').bind('mouseleave', rflipfunc);

});
```

I have tried many solution, but I do not see where the issue is...

Comment: Use `hover` instead. This is what it's for.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle ? It's hard to replicate what you're experiencing.

Comment: @ mrtsherman I tried but I get the loop too. I tried as well spitting the code by the else into the hover({enter},{leave}) but I did not manage.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder what is this jsfiddle?

Comment: @Wiglaf: http://jsfiddle.net/ It's a site to create JS/HTML examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mouseenter` event is triggered when it flips, so you have to detect whether mouse has moved out or not. This is one method to do it.

```
$(window).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    if($(e.target).hasClass("sponsorFlip")){
        mouseMovedOut = false;
    }else{
        mouseMovedOut = true;
    }
});
```

see a demo here ( tested only in FF ) : http://jsfiddle.net/tgg33/7/

Now the div gets flipped only when mouse enters. If you want to flip it back when mouse leaves you have to add `mouseleave` handler.

Comment: What you have written does not work in IE8 would you know why? Is there a func that is not compatible?

Comment: no in firebug there are no errors, it works perfectly in FF. In IE it flips once, then everything is blocked. IE does not give ay error as well

Answer (score 0):

I see what the problem is now and I also see why this was difficult for you to diagnose. The flip animation somehow interferes with the hover event, thus causing it to fall into an infinite loop.

I placed the animated element inside a container - thinking that monitoring the hover event of the outer element would solve the problem. I was very surprised to find that it didn't. When the inner element animates it causes a mouseout event to fire and this causes your infinite loop. I solved it by adding the css property `pointer-events: none` to the sponserFlip div. This isn't supported by IE, but there are workarounds. If this is the way you want to go please let me know.

http://jsfiddle.net/SF2MD/

```
$('.container').hover(function() {
    console.log('hover');
    $(this).children('.sponsorFlip').flip({
        direction: 'lr',
        speed: 250
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).children('.sponsorFlip').flip({
        direction: 'lr',
        speed: 250
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I solved it with the upper post before I saw yours.